# remuxing mpv files from h264 AVI files

Tags: mp4, h.264

I have a bunch of, I think, x264 encoded AVIs that I'd like to convert to m4v so that I can play with Quicktime.  Here's how I created them

First I dump the vob from DVD with this:

```
$ mplayer -dumpstream -dumpfile new.vob dvd://1
```

Then I compress it:

```
$ mencoder -oac copy -o new.avi -ovc x264 -x264encopts crf=18 new.vob
```

I tried doing this to convertthem to m4v, but it's blowing up...

I tried dumping the h264/acc streams:

```
$ mplayer new.avi -dumpvideo -dumpfile new.h264
$ mplayer new.avi -dumpaudio -dumpfile new.acc
```

And remuxing(?) with MP4Box but I'm getting an error:

```
$ MP4Box -add new.h264#video -add new.aac#audio new.m4v
Cannot find H264 start code
Error importing new.h264#video: BitStream Not Compliant
```

So not sure what to do now...

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would just use ffmpeg. ffmpeg has a magic ‘codec’ called `copy` which simply copies the content, rather than re-encoding, which is useful for precisely your use case — changing container without re-encoding.

From the ffmpeg man page:

> **`-vcodec codec`**
>
> Force video codec to codec. Use the "`copy`" special value to
>   tell that the raw codec data must be
>   copied as is.
>
> **`-acodec codec`**
>
> Force audio codec to codec. Use the "`copy`" special value to
>   specify that the raw codec data must
>   be copied as is.

So, to put this into practice:

```
$ ffmpeg -i new.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy new.m4v
```

I use this technique for reformatting H.264 videos inside an FLV container into an MP4 container, which drastically improves lip sync in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: handbrake can't do video passthrough... anything i do in handbrake with this file will compress the video again (even more than it already is)